# Relocation in PE loader

Tags: c, windows, portable-executable

I am trying to make a PE loader to understand more about Portable Executables. The thing I am stuck with is the processing of IAT. I am not able to understand what this piece of code does.

```
PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA nameRef = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((DWORD_PTR)dwMapBase + pImportDesc->Characteristics);
    PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA symbolRef = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)((DWORD_PTR)dwMapBase + pImportDesc->FirstThunk);
    for (; nameRef->u1.AddressOfData; nameRef++, symbolRef++)
    {
        if (nameRef->u1.AddressOfData & 0x80000000)
        {
            symbolRef->u1.AddressOfData = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(hMod, MAKEINTRESOURCE(nameRef->u1.AddressOfData));
        }
        else
        {
            pImportName = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)(dwMapBase + nameRef->u1.AddressOfData);
            symbolRef->u1.Function = (DWORD)GetProcAddress(hMod, (LPCSTR)pImportName->Name);
        }
    }
```

I know that though `Characteristics` we identify the sections for giving the page `READ, WRITE` or `EXECUTE` permissions but nothing of that sort is happening here. By using some already existing codes I have written a PE loader but there is no error and the executable is not getting loaded. Just a hint in the right direction would be sufficient. Thanks.

PS code can be found here https://pastebin.com/0ZEn0i8k

Answer (score 2):

Exactly that piece of code you've placed is intended to only one goal: resolve imports table, so each call to external function could be made with actual address of that imported function. You can take a look at this page to get more technical info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx

> DWORD Characteristics
>
> At one time, this may have been a set of flags. However, Microsoft changed its meaning and never bothered to update WINNT.H. This field is really an offset (an RVA) to an array of pointers. Each of these pointers points to an IMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME structure.

So, your snippet receives a pointer to array of import records as a **nameRef** variable. Then, each import can be one of possible modes:

1. Import by function ordinal number: this is where "if" takes place. Ordinals are always combined with 0x8000000 as user code is never mapped to such a high area. So, that "big eight" just says "this is not an address!".
2. Import by function name: this is "else" branch. Any non-zero **AddressOfData** below "big eight" points to an ASCII-Z string.
3. Zero - this is end-of-import table, dummy record.

And in both non-zero cases, GetProcAddress should resolve an import (by ordinal number or by name) to actual address in memory.

Comment: Doesn't ordinal numbers apply for export table?

Comment: @ashish, both import and export can be done by ordinal or name. In most cases, name-based import/export takes place. Ordinals are great if you plan to compact your PE as much as possible and make it more unfriendly for reverse-engineering. For example, post-loading PE tweaks are more convenient to deal with single byte (ordinal) rather than a name (string).

Comment: Sorry, @ashish, I'm not such a master in PE magic. See MSDN URL in my original answer, it's Matt Pietrek article about PE parsing. Unfortunately, it's old enough to not cover nuances of 64 bit images and NET assemblies so googling is your only hope.

Answer (score -1):

if you look for `IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR` definition, you can view that `Characteristics` is share union with `OriginalFirstThunk`. so really code can be written as

```
PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA nameRef = (PIMAGE_THUNK_DATA)
((DWORD_PTR)dwMapBase + pImportDesc->OriginalFirstThunk);
```

it will be the same effect. however this

`(DWORD)GetProcAddress`
does not cause you any questions ?